# How common the usage of "fortnight" instead of "two weeks ago"?

Tags: word-usage

Today firstly I recovered by [BBC report](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-40273859?ocid=socialflow_facebook&ns_mchannel=social&ns_campaign=bbcnews&ns_source=facebook) that the words "**two weeks ago**" can be replaced by the word "**fortnight**", while so far I didn't came across this thing. How common is this word?

It's not clear to me if "two weeks ago" is used by native English speakers or maybe they should say "fortnight" instead. In other words, I would like to know if I should use it in the spoken language or it's considered weird in spoken language?

> "About a **fortnight** ago, four men were sentenced to one month in prison
>   after eating in public."

Comment: *Fortnight* is widely used as an alternative to *two weeks*. Both forms are perfectly acceptable in written and spoken language, whatever the occasion.

Comment: Are you a British English speaker, @Ronald Sole? I would say "fortnight" is *far* from widely used in American English. I cannot recall the last time I ever heard or read the word.

Comment: Indeed. It can be heard in AuE and NZE as well (that I know), and you can find quantifiable data by searching for it in the [Corpus of Global Web-Based English (GloWbE)](http://corpus.byu.edu/glowbe/).

Comment: @RonaldSole It is much less common in American English than elsewhere; I expect that a very small percentage of USAians could define the word.

Comment: Although I can't speak for its popularity in North America, I have raised no eyebrows with its usage on four continents for half a century or so.

Answer (score 1):

It's very dialectical.  In Canadian English, you'll occasionally see it but its usage seems extremely formal.  In UK English, it seems to be used quite frequently by comparison.